# Vagrant Up Error - guest machine entered an invalid state. Windows 10

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I installed a Laravel Homestead (per project installation). After a successful installation of all the dependencies, I tried to run `vagrant up` but this errors are being thrown.

> The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
>   to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
>   'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
>   properly and try again.

This is my Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: rebuy.dev.se
name: rebuy.dev.se
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "E:/projects/rebuy"
      to: /home/vagrant/rebuy

sites:
    - map: rebuy.se.dev
      to: "/home/vagrant/rebuy/public"

databases:
    - homestead
```

I had already added to my /Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts the IP for my app.

```
192.168.10.10   rebuy.se.dev
```

This is my Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("vendor/laravel/homestead", File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = "Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = "Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = "after.sh"
aliasesPath = "aliases"

require File.expand_path(confDir + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.8.4'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exist? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "/tmp/bash_aliases"
        config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
          s.inline = "awk '{ sub(\"\r$\", \"\"); print }' /tmp/bash_aliases > /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases"
        end
    end

    if File.exist? homesteadYamlPath then
        settings = YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath))
    elsif File.exist? homesteadJsonPath then
        settings = JSON.parse(File.read(homesteadJsonPath))
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, settings)

    if File.exist? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath, privileged: false
    end

    if defined? VagrantPlugins::HostsUpdater
        config.hostsupdater.aliases = settings['sites'].map { |site| site['map'] }
    end
end
```

I'm using Vagrant 1.9.0 and Oracle VM Virtual Box.
Not sure what's causing this error, since I successfully run vagrant on my other computer. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: screenshot of vagrant up error]

Comment: can you post your full Vagrantfile? That would help others provide some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @BrianC, I added my Vagrantfile